a number of measures are taken to minimize


Emergency measures to help the refugees are badly needed.
a number of measures are taken to minimise dust emissions.


Source
The first bold part is part of the subject.
Is the second bold part part of the subject?

Interestingly, you use the American spelling 'minimize' in your title, and the British spelling, 'minimise' in your question. Perhaps you are being impartial?

It would be useful if you could provide a proposed parse tree.

The second sentence is written using a passive verb "are taken".  This means that the grammatical subject plays a role that is normally taken by the object in an active sentence.  Be sure to distinguish grammar from the sematic role.
The grammatical subject is the second sentence is "a number of measures". The infinitive "to minimise" is not part of the noun phrase and would not be bracketed with it in a parse tree.
Does it matter  No. Unless you are doing an academic study of English  (rather than trying to learn the language for communication) spending time on this kind of parsing is probably detrimental to you ability to communicate effectively.

What I'm trying to say is if "a number of measures are taken to minimise dust emissions" is the same as "a number of measures to minimise dust emissions are taken". Does "to minimise dust emissions" modify "measures"?

does it matter?  I suggest you draw a parse tree if you are doing language research.

but generally adverbial phrases like this can move around the sentence fairly freely.
